# What is the cardinality (finite, infinite and countable, or infinite and uncountable) of the smallest model of the following set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

So the set of sentences is such that

$\{\gamma _{\geq n}$ : $n$ is even}

where $\gamma _{\geq n}$ is a sentence such that its models have the cardinality of at least $n$.

I think the answer is that the smallest model of the set is enumerable and infinite, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Wouldn't any countable universe work? It has cardinality at least $2k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Countable and infinite?

Comment: Would a finite set of size $476882$ work?

Comment: no? but i don't know how to justify it

Comment: Can you justify why a domain of size $3$ won't work? Size $4$? Generalize the argument

Comment: @Ned Because $\gamma \geq 6 \in \{\gamma\geq n: n\  is \ even\}$ and $\gamma \geq 6$ only has models of cardinality at least 6. So this rules out models with cardinality less than 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is just going to be the formalization of the answers given by Ned and Harry in the comments.

> **Claim 1**. The set of sentences $\Sigma = \{\gamma_{\geq n} : n \ \ \text{is even}\}$ has no finite models.

**Proof of Claim 1**. Assume for contradiction there exists an $\mathscr L$-structure $\mathscr M$ (in some language $\mathscr L$) such that $\mathscr M \models \Sigma$ and $|\mathscr M| = m$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$. We have two cases:

- If $m$ is even then so is $m+2$, and in this case $\mathscr M \not\models \gamma_{\geq m+2}$ (since $|\mathscr M| = m < m+2$); therefore $\mathscr M \not\models \Sigma$ (since $\gamma_{\geq m+2} \in \Sigma$), a contradiction.
- If $m$ is odd then $m+1$ is even, and in this case $\mathscr M \not\models \gamma_{\geq m+1}$ (since $|\mathscr M| = m < m+1$); therefore $\mathscr M \not\models \Sigma$ (since $\gamma_{\geq m+1} \in \Sigma$), a contradiction.

In both cases we reach a contradiction, so our assumption was false and hence $\Sigma  = \{\gamma_{\geq n} : n \ \ \text{is even}\}$  has no finite models, as required. $\blacksquare$

---

Now that we know that $\Sigma$ has no finite models, we want  to show that it has a countably infinite model.

> **Claim 2**. The set of sentences $\Sigma = \{\gamma_{\geq n} : n \ \ \text{is even}\}$ has a countably infinite model.

**Proof of Claim 2**. We just need to provide a language $\mathscr L$ and an $\mathscr L$-structure $\mathscr M$ such that $\mathscr M \models \Sigma$. Consider $\mathscr L = \varnothing$, so that $\mathscr L$-structures are just sets; in particular, $\mathbb N$ is an infinite $\mathscr L$-structure and we claim that $\mathbb N \models \Sigma$.

Indeed, let $\phi \in \Sigma$, so that $\phi$ is $\gamma_{\geq n}$ for some even natural number $n$. Since $\mathbb N$ is infinite it has at least $n$ elements for every even natural number $n$, so $\mathbb N \models \phi \ $  for all $\phi \in \Sigma$ and thus the claim follows. $\blacksquare$